# Will this cost me two queries for the same thing?

Tags: python, django

I have the normal pagination like this in my view:

```
paginator = Paginator(book_list, 100)
```

And then in my view I am passing the values to my template:

```
return render(request,
...
'paginator': paginator,
...
```

And I have a custom tag for my pagination, which I am loading like this:

```
{% if paginator.count > paginator.per_page %}
    {% load paginator %}
    {% paginator 3 %}
{% endif %}
```

In my custom template pagination tag, I have the following along the code:

```
def paginator(context, adjacent_pages=2):
    page_obj = context['paginator'].page(context['object_list'].number)
    ...
    'hits': context['paginator'].count,
    ...
```

Everything is working as expected but I am worried about `context['paginator'].page(context['object_list'].number)`, is Django fetching the data from DB with this bit or it's using the same data that was fetched from my main view?

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Generally you want to use a profiler to find out how many SQL queries you are executing and the execution time of each query. Check out the [Django Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar).

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter Thanks, that did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paginator keeps the query_set as object_list, in django 1.3.4, the page method, is

```
def page(self, number):
    "Returns a Page object for the given 1-based page number."
    number = self.validate_number(number)
    bottom = (number - 1) * self.per_page
    top = bottom + self.per_page
    if top + self.orphans >= self.count:
        top = self.count
    return Page(self.object_list[bottom:top], number, self)
```

Only the last line related to db,

```
self.object_list[bottom:top]
```

The object_list is just a QuerySet, so the problems comes to if you invoke query_set[x:y] more times, whether there exists multiple queries.

Django's query_set is lazy, if you don't iterate through it, no sql will be triggered. Otherwise, there will be db queries.

You can use check queries in django.db.connection.queries for following code,

```
   from django.db import connection

   original = XXXX.objects.filter(...)
   res1 = original[x:y]
   for item in res1:
     print item
   print len(connection.queries), connection.queries[-1]

   res2 = original[x:y]
   for item in res2:
     print item
   print len(connection.queries), connection.queries[-1]
```

You'll find that the query length grows.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding here is that it's simply using whatever object you passed it in your main view.  `context['paginator']` is going to return the object stored in the `paginator` variable that you passed to the context, an instance of the `Paginator` class.

The question of whether or not it's going back to the database is simply about the `.page(...)` method.  If calling `Paginator.page(...)` issues a database query, then it will be going back to the database--it wouldn't cache that value.  However, if that information is already available locally in the `paginator` variable and that is what is called up by the `.page` method, then you're not refetching the data from the database.